# Access denied errors in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010

I have a dev site that is giving me access denied errors.

In VS 2010 I can hit F5 (Start Debugging) and the site comes up fine. However, if I then click the Home Link I get Error: Access Denied.

If I use the address bar to hit the site URL alone:

```
http://wsgdev/
```

I get access denied.

If I use the address bar to hit the site URL WITH /default.aspx:

```
http://wsgdev/default.aspx
```

The site comes up fine. However, again, if I click Home, I get access denied error again.

Site URL is in hosts file with IP address of dev computer.

I am site collection admin and have full rights throughout the site directly as well.

Site is using Claims Based authentication.

Anonymous Access is enabled. ASP.NET Impersonation is enabled. Windows Authentication is enabled.

OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Site is Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

Site is Essentially a bare site - I have added a pic library and a custom list for testing and can navigate to both successfully.

Ideas?

Thanks,